# How do i get data from one table according to an id field in another?

Tags: php, mysql

So far this loop pulls all the item images from the items table using a method I created and positions them wonderfully.

Now I am trying to use the `$linv['item_id']` to find the item id's of the items in the items table, and pull the data from that table to use between the `<span>` tags (creating a tooltip).

I'm so confused with all the sql calls now.

```
<?php
    $idata = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `items` where `item_id`='".$linv['item_id']."'");
    while($linv = mysql_fetch_array($inv)){
            $idata = mysql_fetch_array($itemdata);
            echo "<a class='tooltips' href='#'><img id='bagicons' src='".getiimage($linv['item_id'])."' />
            <span>
            ".$itemdata['item_name']."
            </span></a>" ;
        }
    ?>
    </div>
    <div id="spacer"> </div>
    <?php
    echo "<div id='char'>".createavatar($_SESSION['uid'])."</div>";
    include("footer.php");
?>
```

Comment: You should note that mySQL is ***deprecated*** and you should be now using MySQLi or PDO with PHP to access the data you need. MySQL has various security flaws and weak interactions and is no longer maintained. Please explore StackOverflow and the web in general as there are lots of tools and blogs about how to learn and pick up MySQLi and PDO quite quickly. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change

```
<?php
$idata = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `items` where `item_id`='".$linv['item_id']."'");
while($linv = mysql_fetch_array($inv)){
        $idata = mysql_fetch_array($itemdata);
        echo "<a class='tooltips' href='#'><img id='bagicons' src='".getiimage($linv['item_id'])."' />
        <span>
        ".$itemdata['item_name']."
        </span></a>" ;
    }
?>
```

to

```
 <?php
while($linv = mysql_fetch_array($inv))
{
    $idata_result_set = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `items` where `item_id`='".$linv['item_id']."'");
    if(mysql_num_rows($idata_result_set) == 0)
        continue;
    $idata = mysql_fetch_array($idata_result_set);
    echo "<a class='tooltips' href='#'><img id='bagicons' src='".getiimage($linv['item_id'])."' />
    <span>
    ".$idata['item_name']."
    </span></a>" ;
}
?>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help @Abdo Adel!
You're ace.

Comment: so after inspecting the correct code, have you figured out what is wrong with the old one? I'm here if you need further explanation